# Python Flask - Stuck on DictReader UnicodeDecode Issues

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I've started learning flask and am stuck with iterating through a csv.

I want to run through a csv that lists the fortune 500 and print them on a page. The CSV has headers Company, Revenues, Profits and Rank.

The error I get is:

```
File "/Project/FLASK/app/templates/companies.html", line 15, in block "content"

<td> {{ keys.Company }} </td>

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x8e in position 3: invalid start byte
```

Below is companies.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block content %}
    <table>
             <tr>
                <td> Company </td>
                <td> Revenues </td>
                <td> Profits </td>
                <td> Rank </td>

           </tr>
        {% for keys in companies %}

           <tr>
                <td> {{ keys.Company }} </td>
                <td> {{ keys.Revenues }} </td>
                <td> {{ keys.Profits }} </td>
                <td> {{ keys.Rank }} </td>

           </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
{% endblock %}
```

Last is my views.py file:

```
@app.route('/companies')
def companies():
    import csv

    with open('companies.csv','rU') as f:
        companies = csv.DictReader(f)


        return render_template("companies.html",
                            title='Home',
                            companies=companies)
```

If I change {{ keys.Company }} to be {{ keys }} the dictionary is displayed but the moment I change to keys.Company or keys.Revenues I get the same error

Comment: What happens if you don't read it in Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

In Jinja2 you have to pass unicode to render functions which consist only ASCII characters. So make the change as:

```
<td> {{ keys.Company.decode('utf-8') }} </td>
```